# keep *nrepl* buffer in cider when jvm terminates

Tags: emacs, clojure, nrepl, cider

I am running a remote nrepl server (`mvn clojure:nrepl`) and connecting via emacs `M-x cider-connect`. When the JVM exists for any reason or I call `(System/exit 0)` in my repl the `*nrepl*` buffer is immediately closed.

How do I prevent that behavior?

How do I make it so that subsequent connections reuse that buffer?

Thanks!

edit: previous: "connecting via emacs `M-x nrepl`"

update:
switched to:

`; CIDER 0.8.0alpha (package: 20141116.1221) (Java 1.7.0_21, Clojure 1.6.0, nREPL 0.2.5)`

if I run `mvn dependency:tree` what I see includes the following:

`[INFO] +- org.clojure:tools.nrepl:jar:0.2.5:compile
[INFO] +- cider:cider-nrepl:jar:0.8.0-SNAPSHOT:compile`

however in Emacs I see the following after a `M-x cider-connect`:

`; CIDER 0.8.0alpha (package: 20141116.1221) (Java 1.7.0_21, Clojure 1.6.0, nREPL 0.2.5)
WARNING: The following required nREPL ops are not supported: 
apropos classpath complete eldoc info inspect-start inspect-refresh inspect-pop inspect-push inspect-reset macroexpand ns-list ns-vars resource stacktrace toggle-trace-var toggle-trace-ns undef
Please, install (or update) cider-nrepl 0.8.0-SNAPSHOT and restart CIDER`

and after closing the REPL and then trying to restart it I see `An nREPL connection buffer already exists ... create a new one? (y or n)`  either answer appears to be the wrong one.

The old buffer isn't deleted at least, but it appears unusable.

Comment: There hasn't been an `nrepl` command in cider for over an year. I'd suggest updating to the current cider first.

Comment: I'll look into updating and comment back / delete this - looks like I'm using just the nrepl 0.2.0 package in emacs (apparently not even cider) -- I'm assuming cider would be better?

Comment: I generally take an if-it-ain't-broke-don't-fix-it approach to emacs, as once I twiddle something I'm usually about to spend a day adjusting all kinds of things.

Comment: Same behavior with this configuration: ; CIDER 0.6.0 (Java 1.7.0_21, Clojure 1.6.0, nREPL 0.2.5)

Comment: Try using the latest master (0.8-snapshot) and if the problem is present there, file an issue [here](https://github.com/clojure-emacs/cider/issues).

Comment: what's the best way to do that? if I use the package manager in the emacs buffer I get 0.6.0, if I use the instructions here https://github.com/clojure-emacs/cider#installation-via-packageel I also get 0.6.0.

Comment: Guess you're using Marmalade. The latest snapshot is on melpa (and the latest stable version is on melpa-stable).

Comment: I've attempted this, moving emacs to 0.8.0 cider, and adding the 0.8.0-SNAPSHOT cider nrepl middleware to my .pom. I'm still having trouble, see above. Thanks for your help.